# DraftJS editor create from HTML is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, editor, draftjs

The editor is starting as if it has empty string!

I tried this:

```
EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText('Hello'))
```

and this:

```
const html = '<p>Hey this <strong>editor</strong> rocks </p>';
const contentBlock = htmlToDraft(html);
if (contentBlock) {
  const contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks);
  const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
  this.state = {
    editorState,
  };
}
```

and this:

```
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs'
htmlToDraft(text)
```

nothing worked!

Answer (score 5):

You don't show what you are doing with the content but the following (i.e. your first option) works correctly

```
<Editor
   editorState={EditorState.createWithContent(
          ContentState.createFromText("Hello")
     )}
/>
```

as does this:

```
import {
   Editor,
   EditorState,
   ContentState,
   convertFromHTML
} from "draft-js";

...

const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(
  "<p>Hey this <strong>editor</strong> rocks </p>"
);

const content = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
  blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
  blocksFromHTML.entityMap
);

return (
      <Editor editorState={EditorState.createWithContent(content)} />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested, I've been bringing in HTML to the Editor for DraftJS via functional components. Here's that code built on top of @Grantnz's answer.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Editor, EditorState, RichUtils, ContentState, convertFromHTML } from 'draft-js'

const DraftJS = () => {
    // assert hard-coded HTML string, convert it, bring it in as state
    const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(
        "<p>Hey this <strong>editor</strong> rocks </p>"
    );

    const content = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
        blocksFromHTML.entityMap
    );

    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createWithContent(content));

    // handle changes to the Editor component
    const onChange = editorState => {
      setEditorState(editorState);
    }

    // build the Editor component
    return (
      <div>
        <h4 className="green-text">From DraftJS.js</h4>
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
}

export default DraftJS;
```

Hope this helps!